# Is it guaranteed freshly opened `/dev/fd/3` always reads from start?

Tags: linux, bash, file-descriptors

This is a Linux-specific question.

The bash script is:

```
echo foo > "a.txt"
exec 3<"a.txt"
cat /dev/fd/3
cat /dev/fd/3
cat /dev/fd/3
```

Output:

```
foo
foo
foo
```

All these `cat`s display the content of `/dev/fd/3`. But `/dev/fd/3` is simply a symlink to `a.txt`. That explains the behavior but I don't know if it's guaranteed (and if so, by what) that:

1. When you run `exec 3<"a.txt"`, `/dev/fd/3` is always a symlink to `a.txt`.
2. Every time you open and read from `/dev/fd/3`, it returns the entire body.

There is an answer to a similar but not entirely same question:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58124/7157

Comment: `cat </dev/fd/3` is more portably written `cat <&3`.  I can't reproduce what you are seeing. Only the first `cat` should output the whole of `a.txt`. In essence, what you have is `{ cat; cat; cat; } <"a.txt"`

Comment: `/dev/fd/3` is most definitely **not** a symlink to anything.

Comment: @Kusalananda If you use `cat <&3` that's true, because the first `cat` moved the file pointer. But if you use `cat </dev/fd/3` it starts from beginning every time. `ls -l` tells me `/dev/fd/3` is a symlink. Maybe it's different on your system?

Comment: @AlexP It's what `ls -l` told me. Similar result on other's system: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74454/somethings-special-about-dev-fd-3

Comment: @Cyker that's what the kernel tells `ls`, to be more friendly. It's not a link. The filesystem itself is virtual, so it's not even a real file.

Comment: Poor `ls -l` had to find a way to show you what was the corresponding file, and that was the best it could do. It still isn't a symlink of any kind. It's just a name for the file descriptor #3 of process.

Comment: @Cyker In any case, I still can't reproduce seeing the contents of `a.txt` three times.   Unless you're in a shell that explicitly documents that `/dev/fd/3` is the same as "filedescriptor 3", there is no connection between `exec 3<a.txt` and `cat /dev/fd/3`

Comment: @AlexP Yes the entire `/proc` filesystem is virtual. The point is if it is provided as a filesystem then it can be used like a filesystem. So if `/dev/fd/3` is shown as a symlink, then it can be used as a symlink.

Comment: @Kusalananda That's weird. Have you tried `cat /proc/self/fd/3` instead? What does `ls -l /dev/fd /dev/fd/3 /proc/self/fd/3` show on your machine?

Comment: @Cyker I don't have `/proc` (I'm not on Linux). The `/dev/fd/3` is a character special file (just like `/dev/tty`), definitely not a symbolic link.

Comment: @Kusalananda Nice. I guess you are on Unix. This is a Linux question... I probably should edit the question adding this.

Comment: Stéphane Chazelas answered this on this site back in 2012.

Comment: @muru stop bamboozling the OP. every file/system is "virtual" on linux. FWIW, yes, __on Linux__ opening `/dev/fd/N` -> `/proc/self/fd/N` -> `/path/to/the/original/file` will always open the original file it points to from scratch, and this is completely different from OpenBSD, Solaris, etc where `open("/dev/fd/N", ...)` will act just like `dup(N)`, ie will duplicate the fd.

Comment: @JdeBP Could you please link its address? I can add in question or mark as dup. Thanks

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58124/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/363072/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/123659/5132 , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/296029/5132 just for starters.